# The Role of "Show" in my sentence

Tags: grammar

I have a question about the subject of below sentence.

This competition to build houses and show dominance led to the destruction of trees.

I think the subject is "This competition to build houses and show dominance" and the verb of this sentence "led to", but What is the grammar role of "Show" in that sentence?
Is "to build houses and show dominance" a noun clause?

Thank you!

Comment: "To" is a preposition.  It's associated phrase includes two verbs conjoined with "and".

Comment: No, _build houses_ and _show dominance_ are two coordinated verb phrases. The marker "to" introduces the coordination. It's easy to tell that they are VPs because each of the verbs has a direct object ("houses" and "dominance"). Nouns of course do not take direct objects

Answer (score 1):

In this question, "competition" is the subject. "led" is the verb. "to build houses and show dominance" is describing the competition and so the entire phrase "competition to build houses and show dominance" should be called either a noun phrase or, I think more accurately, a nominal group.

Refer to: [Nominal Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_group_(functional_grammar))

Answer (score 0):

{to build houses and (to) show dominance}  would be a complement modifying **competition**.  The complement consists of two infinitive phrases.

**Their attempt {to climb the wall and assassinate the king} was thwarted by the palace guard.**

Comment: The competition is a subject. As you said {to build houses and (to) show dominance} is a complement modifying competition, so this part is a subject complement. According to what I know, the subject complement needs linking verb and always uses after this kind of verb. Could you explain what you said, please?